# Queryset Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am having some trouble with a queryset in Django. Unfortunately I cannot use the Django REST Framework built in pagination because it adds unwated JSON fields such as "next", "previous" and "count", so I wanted to limit using the [:10] option on the queryset.

In my attempt below, I am getting the error:
`Queryset Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.`

```
class LocationsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.LocationSerializer
    ordering = ('location_name',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = models.GeonamesLocation.objects.all()
        name_prefix = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('name_prefix', None)
        if name_prefix is not None:
            if len(name_prefix) < 3:
                raise exceptions.ParseError("'name_prefix' must consist of at least 2 characters")
            queryset = queryset.filter(location_name__icontains = name_prefix).order_by('location_name', 'geonames_country', 'geonames_region')[:10]
        return queryset
```

I understand why I would get this error if I applied the `[:10]` before I did order_by, but since I am doing it after, why would it give me this error?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error is happening after queryset is returned by the get_queryset, since LocationViewSet has 'ordering' attribute which tries to re-oder the queryset again.

Answer (score 1):

You can write raw query for 10 result in your code like that it will work,

```
org = Organization.objects.raw('SELECT organization_id, name FROM organization where is_active=1 ORDER BY name limit 10')
```

Keep one thing in a raw query you have to always fetch primary key of table, it's mandatory. Here `organization_id` is a primary key of `contact_organization` table.